# Передача UserControl в CommandParameters

Tags: c#, wpf

Вопрос в следующем. Имеется окно, в котором находятся UserControl-ы в виде модулей (ненужные для демонстрации удалил):

```
<controls:MetroWindow                      
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.5*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="40" />
            <RowDefinition Height="15*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="0.3*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>    

        <central:CentralView Grid.Row="2"
                             ItemsSource="{Binding MainWindowModels}" />

    </Grid>
</controls:MetroWindow>
```

UserControl - CentralView содержит в себе обычный DataGrid с контекстным меню по правому клику на нем. При клике по MenuItem контекстного меню элементы должны передаваться во ViewModel (ViewModel называется CentralViewModel) 1-й элемент DataContext,2-й сам элемент меню и 3-й непосредственно UserControl в котором DataGrid и находится:

```
<MenuItem Command="{Binding NavigateToExtendedWindow}"
          DataContext="{StaticResource CentralViewModel}"
          Header="-">
    <MenuItem.CommandParameter>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ItemMultiValueConverter}">
            <Binding />
            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </MenuItem.CommandParameter>
</MenuItem>
```

Проблема в следующем, передача во ViewModel этого UserControl самого себя не происходит. То-есть первых 2 параментра передаются, а на третьем я получаю {{DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}}. Может ли кто-нибудь подсказать, в чем моя ошибка?

Comment: неправильный у вас какой то MVVM, если он используется. В него не должны передаваться никакие контролы. Вид - по сути проекция вьюмоделей, то есть вьюмодель получающая команду осознает контекст где она и что она.

Comment: Да, согласен. Паттерн тут нарушен. Однако, у меня чисто спортивный интерес, почему не получается передать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что контекстное меню открывается в `Popup`'е, который представляет собой другой корневой элемент. `Parent` у `Popup`'а равен `null`, поэтому поиск вверх по визуальному дереву через `FindAncestor` ничего и не находит. К «содержащему» контекстное меню `DataGrid` можно достучаться через свойство `PlacementTarget`.

Поэтому у вас есть две стратегии.

Во-первых, можно дать корневому элементу имя, и ссылаться через него. Но поскольку в вашем контекстном меню своё внутреннее пространство имён, их нужно связать. Итого: в конструкторе `UserControl`'а

```
NameScope.SetNameScope(GridContextMenu, NameScope.GetNameScope(this));
```

и в XAML'е

```
<UserControl ...
        Name="Root">
    <DataGrid>
        <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu Name="GridContextMenu">
                <Menu>
                    <MenuItem Header="Main">
                        <MenuItem.CommandParameter>
                            <MultiBinding
                                Converter="{StaticResource ItemMultiValueConverter}">
                                <Binding />
                                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
                                <Binding ElementName="Root" />
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </MenuItem.CommandParameter>
                    </MenuItem>
                </Menu>
            </ContextMenu>
        </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
    </DataGrid>
</UserControl>
```

Второй путь — связаться наружу через `PlacementTarget`. Вы должны положить нужный контрол как свойство `PlacementTarget`'а, например, можно использовать `Tag` (всё равно он простаивает).

```
<DataGrid
    Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}">
    <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <Menu>
                <MenuItem Header="Main">
                    <MenuItem.CommandParameter>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ItemMultiValueConverter}">
                            <Binding />
                            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
                            <Binding Path="PlacementTarget.Tag"
                                     RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                             AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </MenuItem.CommandParameter>
                </MenuItem>
            </Menu>
        </ContextMenu>
    </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Благодарю за подсказку.

Comment: @Valery: Пожалуйста, буду рад, если помогло.